# How can I improve the speed of materialized view refreshes and reduce their CPU usage

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have a function that runs every 15 mins to fetch updated/new/deleted records from a number of production databases into a Postgres data warehouse. Once the raw data enters the DB it is transformed and served to clients via materialized views refreshed using the CONCURRENTLY option

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY schemaname.matviewname
```

every 15 mins.
The whole process works well and without failing however it takes too long and consumes too much resources CPU - 1vcpu every 15 mins on Amazon RDS db.t3.large

This might not be enough information to determine the root cause of the CPU utilization and time taken without deeper analysis of the logs but:

1. How can I reduce the amount of time that it takes to refresh a materialized view?
2. How can I reduce the impact of the materialized view refresh (< 1vcpu) every 15 minutes when I am updating the data?

Below is a log of the amount of time it takes to refresh each matview:

```
NOTICE:  Refreshing base metaviews
NOTICE:  Refreshing matview1 Time spent=00:06:08.940783
NOTICE:  Refreshing matview2 Time spent=00:01:51.013243
NOTICE:  Refreshing matview3 Time spent=00:01:08.243421
NOTICE:  Refreshing matview4 Time spent=00:00:24.681019
NOTICE:  Refreshing matview5 Time spent=00:00:03.235798
NOTICE:  Refreshing matview6 Time spent=00:00:20.523829
NOTICE:  Materialized views refreshed.
```

I am currently trying to implement this solution: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/building-fast-refresh-capability-in-amazon-rds-for-postgresql/ have not gotten it to work yet

Comment: Please share the query plan of this materialized view, using EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for the SELECT statement. Please include the DDL for all tables and indexes involved as well

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have added a gist here: https://gist.github.com/mainakibui/bc8fbcfafec1df80313600d2ff3253f9

Comment: At least work_mem is too small, all sorts are done on disk. And disk = slow. Increase work_mem until all your sorts use memory to sort, instead of disk. Some tables and indexes could be better, but without the DDL and the data, hard te predict.

Comment: That took 23 seconds, which is a lot less than 6 minutes.  Is that plan not for the refresh of your slowest MV, or was it just much faster when not run inside a refresh?  You can use auto_explain with auto_explain.log_analyze=on and auto_explain.log_buffers=on to capture the refresh "in the act", and best with track_io_timing also turned on.

Comment: @FrankHeikens thank you for this. Updated work_mem and saw a tremendous improvement on all the other queries except refresh mat views so still looking into that.

Comment: @jjanes updated the plan to the slowest mat view refresh.

Comment: Looks like an IO limitation: The query has to read 2.4GB and that takes a while. Can you improve IO by scaling up?

Comment: Stock PostgreSQL doesn't have a decode function taking a single text argument, so that must be some custom thing.  Maybe that is the bottleneck.  The plan doesn't give any info to help figure that out.  Maybe you can just omit all of these decode functions from the select list and see if that makes a difference.